# Angular 2 - Is it possible to store my routes in another file and import them into the app.ts file (because over time the routes will build up)?

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 2 - Is it possible to store my routes in another file and import them into the app.ts file (because over time the routes will build up)

Here is an example of my current app.ts that works. I basically want to move the route config routes to another file to make it cleaner:

```
   import {Todo} from './components/todo/todo';
   import {About} from './components/about/about';
   import {AuthService} from './authService';

   import {Component, View, bootstrap, bind, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
   import {Router, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
   import {Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app'
   })

   @View({
       template: `
           <div class="container">
               <nav>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a [router-link]="['/Home']">Todo</a></li>
                       <li><a [router-link]="['/About']">About</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </nav>
               <router-outlet></router-outlet>
           </div>
       `,
       directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
   })

   @RouteConfig([
       { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
       { path: '/home', component: Todo, as: 'Home' },
       { path: '/about', component: About, as: 'About' }
   ])

   export class AppComponent {
       constructor(router: Router, _authService: AuthService, _location: Location){

           //Subscribe - watches routes pop state events.
           router.subscribe((val) => {      

               _authService.isUserLoggedIn().then((success) => {                 
                   router.parent.navigate(['/About']);
               });

           })       
       }
   }

   bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}), AuthService]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i personally have created an route.interface.ts and a route.ts files.

> Routes file

```
import {Route} from './route.interface'
import {AuthComponent} from './auth/auth.component'

export const Routes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '/auth',
        name: 'Authenticate',
        component: AuthComponent
    },
];
```

> Route Interface

```
export interface Route {
    path: string,
    name: string,
    component: any,
}
```

Usage in main component.

```
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router'
import {Routes} from './routes'

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './angular2/app/layout.component.html',
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ],
})

@RouteConfig(Routes)
```

Hope that helps. you can even create a route service and inject it you main component. Enjoy coding!

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for my route services

Comment: **Be carefull with the route interface** please consider using their interface  or add the other properties aswell like:
`useAsDefault?: boolean`

Answer (score 2):

You can add your RouteConfig per component

Lets say you have home and about as in your example, then you would define the routing from that specific component in the component itself.

So in your about component you can add

```
 // './components/about/about'

 @RouteConfig([
       { path: '/about', component: About, as: 'About' }
 ])
```

And in your home component you can do the same

```
 // './components/home/home'

 @RouteConfig([
       { path: '/home', component: Todo, as: 'Home' }
 ])
```